# Is CSS 3 Transition do not work with Template element (HTML 5) in case of Adding Class...?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-template

Is Transistion do not work with Template element (HTML5) in case of Adding Class...??

I am using Template of HTML 5 for adding new child to root element via javascript. 
To makes a good visual effect, I am using some CSS transition. Usually, all of transition of CSS is working as well but I can't make it happen with adding new element from HTML 5 Template

Could someone help me please

My code is simplyfied ad bellow

```js
function transform() {
    var root = document.querySelector('#root');
    var template_content = document.querySelector('#myElem').content;
    root.appendChild(document.importNode(template_content, true));
    var el = root.querySelector('.ini');
    console.log(root);
    el.classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.ini {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f0f;
}

.show {
    transition: all 3s ease;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Component Test Bed</h1>
    <!-- <div class="ini"></div> -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <button onclick="transform()">Click</button>
    <template id="myElem">
        <div class="ini"></div>
    </template>
</body>
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty `.setTimeout()` fixes your problem. I have no clue why it does that but I have found this trick to be very useful in different situations.

***Snippet:***

```js
var myElem = document.querySelector('#myElem');
var root = document.querySelector('#root');
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
myButton.addEventListener('click', transform, false);

function transform() {
  root.appendChild(document.importNode(myElem.content, true));
  setTimeout(function() {
    var el = root.querySelector('.ini');
    el.classList.add('show');
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
.ini {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
.show {
  transition: all 3s ease;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Component Test Bed</h1>
<div id="root"></div>
<button>Click</button>
<template id="myElem">
  <div class="ini"></div>
</template>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm6393v3/)** of the same. Hope this helps. **[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)** on **Custom Elements** may also help.

Comment: My god ! but thank anyway.. Tahir Ahmed...:D..may be browser issue..!

Comment: My solution is more complicated..I am using CSS keyframe animation and listen event of animation end to reset CSS..:D

Comment: oh I see. yeah I am not exactly sure why does that happen to be honest. but it could be, just could be, that there are some callbacks available at our disposal whilst creating custom elements. have a read of the article I linked to in my answer. it does talk about a few callbacks, may be you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution but more complicated... By using CSS3 keyframe and listen event of Animation end

CSS

```
.ini {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f0f;
    animation: GROWUP 2s ;
}

@keyframes GROWUP {
  0%   { width: 300px; }
  100% { width: 500px; }
}

function transform() {
    var root = document.querySelector('#root');
    var template_content = document.querySelector('#myElem').content;
    root.appendChild(document.importNode(template_content, true));
    var el = root.querySelector('.ini');
    console.log(root);
        el.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
        console.log(this);
        this.style.height = "50px";
    }, false);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Component Test Bed</h1>
    <!-- <div class="ini"></div> -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <button onclick="transform()">Click</button>
    <template id="myElem">
        <div class="ini"></div>
    </template>
</body>
```