# The <template> tag doesn't work with x-transition in Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, alpine.js

I have this code that works and the animation is nice:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.7.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ open: false }" x-on:click.outside="open = false" x-on:keydown.escape="open = false">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open">
    Click me
  </button>
  <div x-show="open" x-transition>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Dogs</li>
        <li>Cats</li>
        <li>Snakes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I try to use the `<template>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag and change `x-show` to `x-if` (because `x-show` doesn't work with `<template>` tags at all) like this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.7.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ open: false }" x-on:click.outside="open = false" x-on:keydown.escape="open = false">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open">
    Click me
  </button>
  <template x-if="open" x-transition>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Dogs</li>
        <li>Cats</li>
        <li>Snakes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

it can toggle hidden and shown states, but no transition at all.

Any idea how to make `<template>` tags support smooth fade in/out transitions?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350477/5833816 ?

Comment: I am using Alpine.js . Do you think it can be done only via Alpine.js? The whole point of Alpine.js is not using JavaScript calls and stuff too much or only in very simple form. no queries and stuff. But perhaps the setTimeout() function can be used, but I have no idea how. Do you know?

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem too, the only solution I found was adding x-data and x-init attributes and toggling the variable for the x-show directive inside of an $nextTick call. Here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.7.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ open: false }" x-on:click.outside="open = false" x-on:keydown.escape="open = false">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open">
    Click me
  </button>
  <template x-if="open">
    <div x-data="{ show: false }"
         x-init="$nextTick(() => { show = true })"
         x-show="show"
         x-transition>
      <ul>
        <li>Dogs</li>
        <li>Cats</li>
        <li>Snakes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, good job. Any idea how to make the fade out on the click out or pressing esc key? right now only the fade in works. Fade out doesn't.

Comment: @Wodit , I don't think AplineJS has anything that does this. Instructions for removing the DOM element will be executed instantly, unless we change the code to not remove the nodes but to hide them.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as you expect. The reason being is that if you want to use a `<template>` tag in order to hide that section on initial page load with `display: none` (which is a default behavior), transition here will not work. Alpinejs does not support it.

> Unlike x-show, x-if, does NOT support transitioning toggles with
> x-transition.

as you can see on their official [page](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/if).

You should continue using div and avoid template if you want transition animation. It wont even work like this:

```
  <template x-if="open">
    <div x-show="open" x-transition.duration.1500ms>
```

But, maybe you can try something like this:

```
<div x-data="{ open: false, animals: ['Animals'] }" x-on:click.outside="open = false" x-on:keydown.escape="open = false">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open">
    Click me
  </button>
  <template  x-for="animal in animals">
    <div x-show="open" x-transition.duration.1500ms>
      <ul>
        <li>Dogs</li>
        <li>Cats</li>
        <li>Snakes</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: But something like this works with `<template>` and using an animation: ```<div x-data="{ open: false, colors: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow']  }">
      <button @click="open = ! open">Toggle</button>
      <template x-for="color in colors">
        <div>
          <span x-text="color" x-show="open" x-transition.duration.1000ms>
          </span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>```. Try it. Now, I just hoave to find out how to work without the array or something. Any idea how to improve this code to look similar to what I want in my original question?

Comment: Any idea why `x-for` triggers an animation with `<template>` eventhough it shouldn't according to the HTML5 specs of `<template>`?

Comment: x-for does not trigger animation. I believe that the problem with the x-if is how alpine is internally handling showing and hiding of elements. Also, if my answer has solved your problem, could you please mark it as the correct one?

Comment: I will wait for other solutions yet.